# Can i use oauth anthentication to solve authentication issue?

Tags: oauth

In our company we have an external web service that can view, edit and place order. We also have different third party web sites that need to access this web service, but some of third web site are not allowed to place orders, only view them.

Can I use oauth to authenticate the third party web sites? our senior dev suggested using oauth, but according to my reading of the oauth doc, it's talking about that resource user can allow third party to access the server.  I am kind of confused. Are we able to use oauth to solve our problem?

Comment: You can use oauth to let some application have the same rights as you, for some period of time, but without having your credentials. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done with OAuth. The OAuth "scope" parameter is used to tell what the given OAuth access_token can do (Authorization). What you have to do is to check the scopes of the access tokens at the service api, if the access token has the required scope (allowed to place the bids) then it should allow, if it doesn't, then the request should be rejected. The scopes must be associated to the access tokens during the issuance.

Comment: Can I find some example of oauth implementation? I can find client side example but not server side. Where can I find those?